# StoreKit response for products waiting for review

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm developing an iPhone application which will use in-app purchases in order to allow customers to buy products. According to StoreKit doc, I need to send a request to App Store with my product identifiers to get information on them.

My question is: what will the response be if some of the requested products are in the "waiting for review" or "in review" status? Will them be included in SKProductsResponse's invalidProductIdentifiers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the Apple's sandbox environment is not very statable, but normally it should NOT be included in invalidProductIdentifiers. You can still test them by using a test App Store ID with no problem.

Comment: Hi, xuzhe. I meant outside of the sandbox environment: Suppose I've got an accepted iphone application and I create a new in-app purchase item for it, whose identifier is requested but that product is still waiting for review.

Comment: I am not been in such a situation before, but I believe they should be in invalidProductIdentifiers if you are requiring them as they are not been released yet .

Answer (score 0):

The path I take is to have Apps ask a product server under my control for valid product identifiers, then have the App send that response to Apple as a request.  Set the product server such that Apps do not 'see' a product identifier that has yet to be blessed by Apple.

Example: [SKPTBuyButton](https://github.com/jasonb-too/StoreKitPriceTag)

Comment: Yes, that's my model too, altough it's not under my control, but the client's. So I would like to know what will happen if they add an item to the server which has not yet been approved by Apple.